# Subrequest in Symfony / Silex

Tags: php, symfony, curl, httprequest, silex

I'm trying to do a subrequest in Silex / Symfony and I'm doing it like this:

```
$subRequest = HttpFoundation\Request::create('/api/whatsnext', 'GET', array('additionalMessage' => $additionalMessage), $request->cookies->all(), array(), $request->server->all());

return $this->getApp()->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST, false)
```

If I call the function that does this subrequest in the end via a Postman client, it works completely. The function behind that subrequest is handled and the response is returned.

If I'm doing the same call via a curl request, I always get an HTML response looking like this instead of the actual response of the function:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=/api/whatsnext/?additionalMessage=thankYou" />

    <title>Redirecting to /api/whatsnext/?additionalMessage=thankYou</title>
</head>
<body>
    Redirecting to <a href="/api/whatsnext/?additionalMessage=thankYou">/api/whatsnext/?additionalMessage=thankYou</a>.
</body>
</html>
```

Does anybody know how I can get the correct result that postman gets also in the curl request?

My curl request looks like this:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: c081ca0a756ced0df0fcc24546d7e24f" -X POST -d '{"id":4,"answers":[{"answerMessageKey":"savedData","value":"myPrename","matchingAttribute":"prename","matchingService":"UserService"}]}' http://the-url-to-the-function-that-has-the-subrequest-in-the-end.local
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: isn't `/api/whatsnext` a route available with the `GET` method? why are you using `POST` on your curl request?

Comment: /api/whatsnext is a route for GET, correct. The URL in the curl request is a Different URL to a different function. And that function is doing the GET subrequest to /api/whatsnext in the End.